# Kohana 3.2 ORM many-to-many - wrong field names

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3.2

I trying to make many-to-many relation between 2 models: Users_Role and Users_Right

```
class Model_Users_Role extends ORM{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'rights' => array(
            'model'   => 'users_right',
            'through' => 'users_roles_rights',
        ),
    ); 
}

class Model_Users_Right extends ORM{    
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'roles' => array(
            'model'   => 'users_role',
            'through' => 'users_roles_rights',
        ),
    );
}
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
$role = ORM::factory('users_role', 1);
$right = ORM::factory('users_right', 1);
$right->add('roles', $role);
```

Error:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'role_id' in 'field list' [ INSERT INTO `users_roles_rights` (`users_right_id`, `role_id`) VALUES ('1', '1') ]
```

---

I tryed to make it on the other side:

```
$role = ORM::factory('users_role', 1);
$right = ORM::factory('users_right', 1);        
$role->add('rights', $right);
```

New error:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'right_id' in 'field list' [ INSERT INTO `users_roles_rights` (`users_role_id`, `right_id`) VALUES ('1', '1') ]
```

I expected ORM to use `users_role_id` and `users_right_id` field names in pivot table, but it uses wrong name of far key? Where I have made a mistake?

Comment: I added 'far_key' into array, data was added successfully. But if I try to add the same relation second time, kohana ads one more same row into pivot table. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out where the [default values are set](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/orm.php#L326).
Try this:

```
class Model_Users_Role extends ORM{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'rights' => array(
            'model'   => 'users_right',
            'far_key' => 'users_right_id',
            'through' => 'users_roles_rights',
        ),
    ); 
}

class Model_Users_Right extends ORM{    
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'roles' => array(
            'model'   => 'users_role',
            'far_key' => 'users_role_id',
            'through' => 'users_roles_rights',
        ),
    );
}
```

Kohana does not check that the relationship does not already exist.

Either enforce this in the database table with a composite unique key on the two foreign key columns, or make your code check that the relationship does not already exist before adding.